# Grails String.encodeAsBase64() Fails in Spock Tests

Tags: unit-testing, grails, spock

This code works fine when I run it in Grails.

```
String getLoginToken() {
    generatePassword()
    passwordExpired = false
    [email, password].join(',').encodeAsBase64()
}
```

However, this Spock test fails

```
def "test getLoginToken"() {
    setup:
    String email = "bacon@eggs.edu"
    Person person = new Person(email: email)

    when:
    String token = person.getLoginToken()

    then:
    token.decodeBase64() == "$email,$person.password"
}
```

with the following exception

```
| Failure:  test getLoginToken(com.campuscardtools.myphotoid.PersonSpec)
|  groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.String.encodeAsBase64() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: decodeBase64()
    at com.campuscardtools.myphotoid.Person$$EPFScS6i.getLoginToken(Person.groovy:140)
    at com.campuscardtools.myphotoid.PersonSpec.test getLoginToken(PersonSpec.groovy:68)
```

My understanding is that Groovy provides the encodeAsBase64() on the String class (see: http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/11/groovy-goodness-base64-encoding.html), so why doesn't this work in the unit test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than

```
"Blah".encodeAsBase64()
```

You need

```
"Blah".encodeBase64()
```

Without the 'As'

Comment: <facepalm> Just out of curiosity, where does the method encodeAsBase64 come from? Grails must be adding that to the metaclass. Can anyone link to the docs for it? Thanks for the help!

Comment: The Grails `encodeAsXXX` methods are from codecs and are described at https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.x/ref/Plug-ins/codecs.html

Answer (score 1):

You could also include a mockCodec for the method you're using.

```
and: "add the Base64 codec"
    mockCodec(org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.codecs.Base64Codec)
```

Answer (score 0):

This works, but I fells like a bad hack.  Surely there must be cleaner solution:

```
def cleanup () {
    String.metaClass = null
}

def "test getLoginToken"() {
    setup:
    String email = "bacon@eggs.edu"
    Person person = new Person(email: email)
    String encoded = null

    and:
    String.metaClass.encodeAsBase64 {
        encoded = delegate
        return delegate
    }

    when:
    String token = person.getLoginToken()

    then:
    token == "$email,$person.password"
    encoded == "$email,$person.password"
}
```